# Relating Minkowski and Schwarzschild

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

In the article https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0309072 the author finds a link between Minkowski coordinates of a freely falling observer and Schwarzschild coordinates. He makes use of a Galilean simplification and gets the Painlevè-Gullstrand coordinates. Obviously, this operation works only locally since there is no global coordinate transformation relating two different solutions (i.e. different energy momentum content of Einstein Field Equations) describing two different manifolds. I want to make this more quantitative in my mind, in order to understand the very roots of the problem from another perspective. Going from Schwarzschild to Minkowski makes clear to me how locality enters through the definition of a comoving tetrad over the freely falling observer (vanishing metric and first derivatives on the geodesic), but the viceversa is not clear to me. I was trying to rely on the Bergmann-Komar group, maybe by showing how the quantities associated to the transformation presented in the article doesn't close the symmetry group, but it is a bit puzzling.